# What will String.replaceAll() return if it can't find the desired string?

Tags: java, regex, string

If String.replaceAll() doesn't find the desired replacement string, what will it return?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It will return the original string. the replaceAll replaces all matches, it does not matter if there are 0, 1 or 1000.

Answer (score 3):

It will return the original, input String.

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29):

> public String replaceAll(String regex,
>                            String replacement)
>
> Replaces each substring of this string that matches the given regular
>   expression with the given replacement.

Test:

```
String input = "aaa";
String result = input.replaceAll("b", "c"); // Replace "b" letters for "c".
System.out.println(result); // Prints "aaa".
```